# If $X$ is an infinite set, then is $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |X|=|X|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I used the above to solve a problem, but I am not sure if this is true (and if it is true does it require a proof or is it obvious). I think it is true because $|X| + |X| = |X|$, so it should follow that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |X|=|X|$. However, I am getting confused because I do not know if there may be different 'rules' for infinite sums of cardinals.

Comment: It definitely requires proof. This is equivalent to $|X\times \mathbb N|=|X|$ when $X$ is infinite.

Comment: What is your definition of $|X| + |X|$.  Cardinalities aren't numbers and you can't do arithmetic on them.  What is your definition of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |X|$?

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews It does require proof.  But your comment is not accurate.$ |X\times N|=|X|$ follows immediately from $|X|+|X|=|X|$. However, the equation holding for $N\to \infty$ requires further proof.

Comment: Usually an expression like $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$  is defined to take values in the extended reals $[0,\infty]$.  Here $\infty$ isn't meant as a cardinality, it's just a symbol

Comment: @fleablood Cardinalities *are* numbers (under assumption of Axiom of Choice), and you can [definitely do arithmetic on them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic). It doesn't work like finite arithmetic, though.

Comment: $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n |X| = |X|$, so it would seem like it's a good idea to say $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |X| = |X|$ as a 'limit' of a constant sequence. I have no idea what topology cardinals usually have though, I've heard of order topologies before though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the context. In particular it depends on the Axiom of Choice. Since you put the "cardinals" and "elementary-set-theory" tags on it, I will treat it as a set theoretic question. If instead this question arose from some application (say group theory), then feel free to just assume the Axiom of Choice.

### Definitions

In general we have the following definitions for adding cardinalities: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets, then $|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|$. If $\kappa$ is a cardinal number, then we can generalise this by defining the sum $\sum_{\xi<\kappa}|A|$ as the disjoint union of $\kappa$ many sets of size $|A|$.

We can define cardinal multiplication as $|A|\cdot |B|=|A\times B|$.

Although $\infty$ as a symbol is too vague for set theoretic purposes, I guess that with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$ you mean to say $\sum_{i\in\omega}$, where $\omega=\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ is the set of finite ordinals, or natural numbers.

### With Axiom of Choice

Under the assumption of the Axiom of Choice every set can be well-ordered, and thus every set has a cardinality equal to a cardinal number. In this case we could show that addition and multiplication of infinite cardinals are quite trivial. In particular, one could show for both $A$ and $B$ infinite sets, 
 that $|A|+|B|=|A|\cdot |B|=\max\{
|A|,|B|\}$, and thus $|X|+|X|=|X|$ for an infinite set $X$ is indeed true under the assumption of the Axiom of Choice.

We can see $\sum_{i\in\omega} |X|$ as the cardinality of the union of $\{X\times\{i\}\mid i\in\omega\}=X\times\omega$. Since $X$ was assumed to be infinite, we then get $|X\times\omega|=\max\{|X|,\omega\}=|X|$.

Note that it does not hold in general that $\sum_{\xi\in\kappa}|X|=|X|$ for any cardinal $\kappa$. To be precise, $\sum_{\xi\in\kappa}|X|=\max\{\kappa,|X|\}$ if $\kappa$ is infinite and $X\neq\varnothing$.

### Without Axiom of Choice

Without the Axiom of Choice, it gets very difficult to say what the size of $\sum_{i\in\omega} |X|$ is. For example, without choice, it is possible that the countable union of countable sets is uncountable, and thus we cannot claim that $\sum_{i\in\omega}|X|=|X|$. This also shows that it becomes unreasonable to give any meaning to taking the sum of arbitrary cardinalities, since it does not have a fixed value: the value depends on which sets we take the cardinality of. In other words, even if $|A_i|=|B_i|$ for all $i\in\omega$ and for every $i\neq j$ we have $A_i$ and $A_j$, and $B_i$ and $B_j$, disjoint from each other, it could be that $\left|\bigcup_{i\in\omega} A_i\right|\neq\left|\bigcup_{i\in\omega} B_i\right|$

In fact, even finite sums become problematic: without the Axiom of Choice there could exist [Dedekind-finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) infinite sets. If $X$ is a Dedekind-finite infinite set, then the cardinality of the disjoint union $|X\sqcup X|$ is still Dedekind-finite, which implies that $|X|+|X|>|X|$.